# How to programmatically get language info and salesChannel info for a category entity written event(subscriber) in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware

I have written Administration subscriber event on category which triggers every category written events and i would like to get translations data **language**(*english/german*) and **sales channel** information of current category.

Let's say system having two languages(English and German) and three sales Channels(us.shopware.com, ae.shopware.com and eu.shopware.com), and admin is making some changes in category data then, so `onWrittenEvent` I want to get two names(English and German) plus all other properties which are translatable such as `description` etc.. and also if current category (which is being written) is belongs to all three sales channels or single sales channel?

**File: services.xml**

```
<service id="Custom\SW6\Subscriber\CatSubscriber">
            <argument id="category.repository" type="service"/>
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

**File: CatSubscriber.php**

```
<?php

namespace Custom\SW6\Subscriber;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Category\CategoryEvents;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Media\MediaEntity;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityDeletedEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityWrittenEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class CatSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /**
     * @var EntityRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $categoryRepo;

    public function __construct(
        EntityRepositoryInterface $categoryRepo
     
    )
    {
        $this->categoryRepo = $categoryRepo;

    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CategoryEvents::CATEGORY_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'onCategoryWrite'
        ];
    }



    public function onCategoryWrite(EntityWrittenEvent $event): void
    {
            $writeResults = $event->getWriteResults();

            $catIds = array();
            foreach ($writeResults as $result) {
                $catIds = $result->getPrimaryKey();
            }
            $categoryCriteria = new Criteria([$catIds]);
            //$categoryCriteria->addAssociation('salesChannel.domains');
            $categories = $this->categoryRepo->search($categoryCriteria, $event->getContext())->getEntities();
            
            $data = array();
            foreach ($categories as $row) {
                $data[]['id'] = $row->getId();
                //$data[]['salesChannelId'] = $row->getSalesChannelId();
                //$data[]['langId'] = $row->getLangId();
            }
    }
    
}
```

I would like to fetch current category entity belongs to which **language** and which **sales channel** something like in `$data` object ?

Comment: What problem do you want to solve exactly? It is not clear from the question. Any way category can have translations in all system languages and actually, translations belong to the category.

Regarding sales channels the is no easy way to define which sales channel category belongs to. You need to find is some parent category or exactly written category are assigned as one of the navigation roots to sales channel (main navigation, footer navigation, etc.)

Comment: @ValeriiPravoslavnyi added more notes in question.